# After Migrating to AndroidX, i got this Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, androidx

After Migrating to AndroidX from Refactor tools in Android Studio, i got this error - 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class ..

Before i was Working Perfectly but only after migrating it was coming up with these errors in some activities..

StackTrace :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pumosoft.naveenkadiyala.familychoice/com.pumosoft.naveenkadiyala.familychoice.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.pumosoft.naveenkadiyala.familychoice.Login.onCreate(Login.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.pumosoft.naveenkadiyala.familychoice.Login.onCreate(Login.java:44) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.isColorInt(AppCompatResources.java:163)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.inflateColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:110)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:76)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:366)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:247)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.pumosoft.naveenkadiyala.familychoice.Login.onCreate(Login.java:44) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15330 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

My XML Code:

> ```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:background="@drawable/bg__gradient"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     tools:context=".Login">
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/log_title"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
>         android:fontFamily="@font/berkshire_swash"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:text="@string/app_name"
>         android:textColor="#fff"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/_47ssp" />
>
>     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
>         android:id="@+id/log_email"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
>         android:textColorHint="#fff"
>         app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
>         app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout">
>
>         <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_light"
>             android:hint="@string/email"
>             android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
>             android:textColor="#fff"
>             app:backgroundTint="#fff" />
>     </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
>
>     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
>         android:id="@+id/log_password"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
>         android:textColorHint="#fff"
>         app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
>         app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
>         app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
>         app:passwordToggleTint="#FFF">
>
>         <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_light"
>             android:hint="@string/password"
>             android:inputType="textPassword"
>             android:textColor="#fff"
>             app:backgroundTint="#fff" />
>     </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/Login_forgotPass_btn"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
>         android:gravity="right"
>         android:text="@string/forget_password"
>         android:textColor="#FFF"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>     <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
>         android:id="@+id/log_log_card"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
>         app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
>         app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_8sdp">
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/log_login_btn"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
>             android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
>             android:text="@string/cap_login"
>             android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp"
>             android:textStyle="bold" />
>     </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
>
>     <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
>         android:id="@+id/log_reg_card"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
>         app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
>         app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_8sdp">
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/log_signup_btn"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
>             android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
>             android:text="@string/cap_register"
>             android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
>             android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp"
>             android:textStyle="bold" />
>     </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: can you paste your xml layout file

Comment: Yes, Updated plz check once

Answer (score 2):

I was facing something similar and my problem was that one of the layout files was still using the support library after migrating to AndroidX. Found that by reading the whole stack trace.

[image]

Comment: No problem. Reading your stack trace a bit more it seems the error is due to a `resource not found`. Maybe check your `colours, drawables, styles or layout files` as the error could be coming from there.

Comment: Yaah even i have the same problem and resolved it by changing that xml file

Answer (score 1):

Issues looks like in this styles.

```
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout
```

Btw I assumed you have support design library defined in build.gradle

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
```

Comment: i have implemented support library but it doesn't works and now i m using the backedup zip file and its working fine.. but i cant get what's the error in using androidx libraries...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that drove me crazy for a whole day. I found out that my styles document in res folder had other versions (v19 and v23) that still had appcompat in their themes despite fixing that in the regular styles sheet. I just deleted the other styles sheet and it worked.